# Design an encrypted time-limited API on Client/Server side

Tags: python, django, api, python-3.x, encryption

I am planning design an encrypted time-limited API on both Client and Server sides, the server side is written in Django, the client side is a GUI program which call the API by

```
import requests
c = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/VideoParser/", data={'videoUrl': videoUrl })
```

The way it call the API is desperately exposed to those who can use  network traffic capturing tools like wireshark and fiddler, while I don't want anyone else could call the API with their customized `videoUrl`, and if people made the post call with the same parameters 2 minutes later after the client initially made the call, the call should be valid or expired, so how to design the encrypted time-limited API on  both Client and Server side in this case ?

---

P.S. I think add an `identifier` to the post `data` could prevent them using the API

```
import requests
c = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/VideoParser/", data={'videoUrl': videoUrl, 'identifier':value_of_identifier })
```

provided there is something  encrypted in the `value_of_identifier` and it changes with each call, but I don't know how to get started, any idea ?

It would be better to show some code , I really don't know how to start to write code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will address your objectives:

1. Create an **access key** and a **secret key** for each user who is allowed to make requests.
2. Give one copy of each key to the user and keep one copy of each key on the server.
3. Add the following two parameters to each request: **timestamp, and access key**
4. Require that when the user sends a request, she creates a string of the post request, along with a timestamp parameter, and **hash it using SHA256, using the secret key**. (any hashing algo will do)
5. Create a parameter named **Signature** in your Post request, and use the hashed string as the value of the signature.
6. When the request reaches the server, use the access key to retrieve that user's secret key, and hash the request again. This will re-create the signature. **The signature created at the server and one sent by the user must match.**

If the two signatures don't match, discard. This way, anyone listening on the wire will have the url as well as the access keys, but will not be able to create a valid signature without the secret key associated with the access key.

Since there is a timestamp involved, the attacker will not be able to re-use a stolen signature.

Amazon uses this technique. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

Comment: Thanks, but it would be better to show some code , I really don't know how to start to write code.

Comment: Read through the link I provided, Amazon has pretty good documentation about how to do the client side of it. You would have to think it through very carefully about how to implement the server side. There is also the question of generating and sharing the secret key, this can be a weak point if not done correctly. There is a lot that can go wrong, I suggest finding an open source library and using it or using it as reference.